# How do I recover from a socket error? (10040)

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a UDP sender and a UDP listener. Transfering messages works nicely. But...

It appears when I am overfeeding (sending sustained data quickly) the listening socket may throw on the call to ReceiveFrom with error code 10040 which means some buffer was not large enough. The exception message is

> A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal
> message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to
> receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself.

Fair enough. But the problem is I will then get this exception on every following call to ReceiveFrom. The socket appears broken. I am willing to accept the transfer failed but I now want to flush the socket's receive buffer and continue.

I can prevent this from happening by setting a substantial receive buffer size of 128K on the listening socket (as opposed to the default of 8K). I can also fix it by having the sender pause for 1 ms after sending a chunk of 65507 bytes of a multi-chunk bulk message.

But I do not feel safe. If this exception still occurs, I want to log and continue (better luck next time). Recreating the socket and restarting the listen thread seems blunt. Is there a better way?

Something unrelated I do not like: Socket.ReceiveFrom throws an exception after the timeout. This is stupid, timeouts are normal behavior. I would expect a TryReceiveFrom method and I do not like using the exception handler as a flow control statement, which seems to be the only option I have. Is there a better way?

[Edit]

On further scrutiny (I ran into exceptions being thrown again after sending messages in one piece in an effort to optimize) I found the main reason for my troubles. It turns out the ReceiveFrom method is not the friendliest API...

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefrom?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-socket-receivefrom(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32-system-net-sockets-socketflags-system-net-endpoint@)) it says:

> "With connectionless protocols, ReceiveFrom will read the first
> enqueued datagram received into the local network buffer. If the
> datagram you receive is larger than the size of buffer, the
> ReceiveFrom method will fill buffer with as much of the message as is
> possible, and throw a SocketException."

In other words: with UDP a full datagram will always be returned regardless the size argument, which is effectively ignored in its capacity as a limiter, and you'd better make sure your buffer is big enough.

So you want the buffer passed to ReceiveFrom to be at least 64K in order for it to be big enough for the biggest possible datagram, see what you got by checking the return value and work with that.

It gets a little worst still: the size argument is not entirely ignored, if offset plus size exceeds the length of your buffer you also get an exception. So it is ignored on the one hand because it does not limit the number of bytes being written to your buffer but it is still being sanity-checked.

After discovering this quirk and respecting it I did have not had any overruns, no matter how hard I bashed it from the sending end (I send a large bitmap repeatedly without pausing). The report on my journey my save others some frustration.

Comment: Yes, this is how it works -- once you get an exception on a socket, it's dead, and you'll have to get a new one (barring things that never hit the network stack of course, like an argument exception). A timeout on the socket is also not considered "normal", but a sign that the connection is dead because the other side sent nothing in the expected time frame. The usual approach is to keep a read pending indefinitely (by using no timeout, which is the default), ending it only when the connection or the application shuts down, by disposing the socket. Async comes recommended there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert is that really how it works in C#? It's *not* how it works in the nuderlying Win32 API, AFAIK! Note this is a connectionless socket.

Comment: @user253751: that's true, I'm so used to connected sockets that I don't know the behavior of connectionless ones that well. The .NET layer is a thin wrapper over Winsock, so if the socket remains usable per Winsock rules it'll still be usable in .NET too (well, normally). For connected sockets, pretty much any error spells doom.

Comment: Try using SocketFlags.Partial. Does that work?

Comment: Maybe you need a raw `Dgram` socket? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettype?view=net-6.0

Comment: Applying SocketFlags.Partial does not seem to make a difference. Blocking indefinately is unsatisfying, I would have to dispose the socket possibly in the middle of an operation (does not feel right). I want to use a stop flag and end my listen thread gracefully. I now solved it with a try catch around the while (!stop) loop and another while (!stop) around that. If something throws (that is not a timeout) the socket will be disposed and recreated. If stop is set it will leave both loops. This seems to work well for now. I may want to look at async operation... Thanks for the tips so far.

Answer (score 0):

I accept now that when the buffer overruns, the socket is broken and needs to be recreated.

The exception being thrown after a timeout of `Socket.ReceiveFrom` can be prevented by first checking if any data is available using the `Socket.Poll` method. This has its own timeout argument. So it is pointless to set `ReceiveTimeout` on the socket, using `Poll` in tandem with `ReceiveFrom` works much nicer.